# exchange multi-tenant 2010 server failed on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

I have an Exchange multi-tenant 2010 server on windows server 2008 r2 which has become unstable hence i decided to rebuild my exchange multi-tenant server as the easiest fix and was planning to move all emails across manually.
I have a well documented guide that i follow for setting up my exchange 2010 multi-tenant on windows server 2008 r2 with all prerequisites which i have followed many times and successfully setup the Exchange 2010 multi-tenant on windows server 2008 r2 so i am sure there is no problems in the setup stage
.
Today i have setup an exchange 2010 windows server 2008 r2 machine. I created a test account ensured all was working and okay from sending to receiving email which was all fine in preparation to manually recreate each mailbox account and then manually move the emails across.

I had not started moving any emails across luckily but in the evening i tried sending and receiving a test emails from the test account that was created. I did not receive the email or the email did no go out. when opening outlook it showed trying to connect.

I tried restarting the windows server 2008 r2 but it takes forever on applying computer setting and when logging in applying user settings due to services not starting up. i am surprised why it failed all of a sudden and services are not starting as it was working fine. I can easily rebuild the server as it does not contain any data but as its not got any data i can play around with this server and take steps to see if i can get to the bottom of this which i would like to with any input from anyone.

what i have tried so far is enabling ipv6 which was disabled.

note:I did the first test of send receive email which was successful before exchange IIS certificate was installed. the second test which failed was after installing the certificate.

system log file sample

```
Level   Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category
Error   07/08/2017 23:27:37 Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy   1055    None    "The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller. 
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller)."
Error   07/08/2017 23:26:51 Service Control Manager 7031    None    The Microsoft Exchange Address Book service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
Information 07/08/2017 23:25:59 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Diagnostic System Host service entered the stopped state.
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:33 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Windows Modules Installer service entered the running state.
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:31 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Network Connections service entered the running state.
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:25 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state.
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:25 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Windows Installer service entered the running state.
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:24 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Shell Hardware Detection service entered the running state.
Error   07/08/2017 23:23:24 Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy   1053    None    "The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the user name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller. 
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller)."
Error   07/08/2017 23:20:43 Service Control Manager 7031    None    The Microsoft Exchange Address Book service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
Information 07/08/2017 23:15:15 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Shell Hardware Detection service entered the stopped state.
Error   07/08/2017 23:14:36 Service Control Manager 7031    None    The Microsoft Exchange Address Book service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
Information 07/08/2017 23:13:22 Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon  7001    (1101)  User Logon Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program
Information 07/08/2017 23:13:15 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Shell Hardware Detection service entered the running state.
Error   07/08/2017 23:09:44 TermDD  50  None    The RDP protocol component X.224 detected an error in the protocol stream and has disconnected the client.
Error   07/08/2017 23:09:22 Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy   1055    None    "The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller. 
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller)."
Error   07/08/2017 23:08:28 Service Control Manager 7031    None    The Microsoft Exchange Address Book service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
Error   07/08/2017 23:02:21 Service Control Manager 7031    None    The Microsoft Exchange Address Book service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
Information 07/08/2017 23:00:29 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the stopped state.
Information 07/08/2017 22:56:33 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Portable Device Enumerator Service service entered the stopped state.
Error   07/08/2017 22:56:14 Service Control Manager 7031    None    The Microsoft Exchange Address Book service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
Information 07/08/2017 22:54:33 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Portable Device Enumerator Service service entered the running state.
Error   07/08/2017 22:54:32 Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy   1055    None    "The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller. 
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller)."
Information 07/08/2017 22:53:59 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Application Experience service entered the stopped state.
Information 07/08/2017 22:51:01 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The SPP Notification Service service entered the running state.
Error   07/08/2017 22:50:06 Service Control Manager 7031    None    The Microsoft Exchange Address Book service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service.
Error   07/08/2017 22:49:38 Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager  1067    None    "The terminal server cannot register 'TERMSRV' Service Principal Name to be used for server authentication. The following error occured: The RPC server is unavailable.
."
Warning 07/08/2017 22:47:25 Microsoft-Windows-WinRM 10154   None    "The WinRM service failed to create the following SPNs: WSMAN/mail.mymailsvr.com; WSMAN/mail. 

 Additional Data 
 The error received was 1722: %%1722.

 User Action 
 The SPNs can be created by an administrator using setspn.exe utility."
Information 07/08/2017 22:46:25 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Microsoft Exchange Transport service entered the stopped state.
Information 07/08/2017 22:46:01 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) service entered the running state.
Information 07/08/2017 22:46:01 Microsoft-Windows-WinRM 10148   None    "The WinRM service is listening for WS-Management requests. 

 User Action 
 Use the following command to see the specific IPs on which WinRM is listening: 

 winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener"
Information 07/08/2017 22:46:00 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Windows Defender service entered the running state.
Information 07/08/2017 22:46:00 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Software Protection service entered the running state.
Information 07/08/2017 22:46:00 Service Control Manager 7036    None    The Distributed Transaction Coordinator service entered the running state.
```

application log file sample

```
Level   Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category
Error   07/08/2017 23:31:56 MSExchange Common   4999    General "Watson report about to be sent for process id: 3328, with parameters: E12, c-RTL-AMD64, 14.01.0218.015, M.E.AddressBook.Service, unknown, unknown, M.E.Common.ExServiceBase+ServiceTimeoutException, 0, unknown.
ErrorReportingEnabled: False"
Error   07/08/2017 23:31:49 MSExchangeAB    1002    General Failed to register service principal name exchangeAB. Failed with error code The RPC server is unavailable (1722).
Error   07/08/2017 23:26:48 MSExchangeAB    1004    General An unexpected error occurred while starting the Microsoft Exchange Address Book service. Error details: The wait operation timed out (258)
Error   07/08/2017 23:26:12 MSExchangeAB    1002    General Failed to register service principal name exchangeAB. Failed with error code The RPC server is unavailable (1722).
Error   07/08/2017 23:25:48 MSExchange Common   4999    General "Watson report about to be sent for process id: 5652, with parameters: E12, c-RTL-AMD64, 14.01.0218.015, M.E.AddressBook.Service, unknown, unknown, M.E.Common.ExServiceBase+ServiceTimeoutException, 0, unknown.
ErrorReportingEnabled: False"
Warning 07/08/2017 23:23:53 MSExchange Mailbox Replication  1007    Service "The Mailbox Replication service was unable to determine the set of active mailbox databases on a mailbox server.
Mailbox server: mail.mymailsvr.com
Error: MapiExceptionNetworkError: Unable to make admin interface connection to server. (hr=0x80040115, ec=-2147221227)
Diagnostic context:
    ......
    Lid: 15000   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: prm[1]: Pointer val: 0x0000000000000000
    Lid: 15000   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: prm[2]: Pointer val: 0x0000000000000000
    Lid: 16280   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: ComputerName: n/a
    Lid: 8600    dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: ProcessID: 3164
    Lid: 12696   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Generation Time: 2017-08-07 22:23:32:847
    Lid: 10648   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Generating component: 18
    Lid: 14744   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Status: 10060
    Lid: 9624    dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Detection location: 318
    Lid: 13720   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Flags: 0
    Lid: 11672   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: NumberOfParameters: 0
    Lid: 24060   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 23746  
    Lid: 31938   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 19650  
    Lid: 27842   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 20866  
    Lid: 29058   StoreEc: 0x80040115"
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:30 MsiInstaller    1042    None    Ending a Windows Installer transaction: http://js.mykings.top:280/helloworld.msi. Client Process Id: 2208.
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:25 MsiInstaller    1040    None    Beginning a Windows Installer transaction: http://js.mykings.top:280/helloworld.msi. Client Process Id: 2208.
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:24 Desktop Window Manager  9003    None    The Desktop Window Manager was unable to start because a composited theme is not in use
Information 07/08/2017 23:23:24 Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon  4101    None    Windows license validated.
Warning 07/08/2017 23:23:24 Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon  6006    None    The winlogon notification subscriber <GPClient> took 601 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logon).
Warning 07/08/2017 23:22:15 MSExchangeRepl  4121    Service The Microsoft Exchange Replication service encountered an error when retrieving the database copy statuses during the periodic operation 'AmPeriodicDatabaseStateAnalyzer'. The operation will be retried later.
Error   07/08/2017 23:20:41 MSExchangeAB    1004    General An unexpected error occurred while starting the Microsoft Exchange Address Book service. Error details: The wait operation timed out (258)
Warning 07/08/2017 23:20:33 MSExchange ActiveSync   1022    Requests    "The connection between the Client Access server and Mailbox server ""mail.mymailsvr.com"" failed. If this event is logged infrequently or only during scheduled downtime for a Mailbox server, no user action is required. If this event occurs repeatedly, check network connectivity using PING or PingPath. Also, check connectivity using the Test-ActiveSyncConnectivity cmdlet. More information: 

Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ConnectionFailedTransientException: Cannot open mailbox /o=Exchsvr/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=rehan. ---> Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionNetworkError: MapiExceptionNetworkError: Unable to make connection to the server. (hr=0x80004005, ec=2423)
Diagnostic context:
    ......
    Lid: 16280   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: ComputerName: n/a
    Lid: 8600    dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: ProcessID: 2496
    Lid: 12696   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Generation Time: 2017-08-07 22:20:12:652
    Lid: 10648   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Generating component: 18
    Lid: 14744   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Status: 10060
    Lid: 9624    dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Detection location: 318
    Lid: 13720   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: Flags: 0
    Lid: 11672   dwParam: 0x6BA      Msg: EEInfo: NumberOfParameters: 0
    Lid: 53361   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 51859  
    Lid: 33649   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 43315  
    Lid: 58225   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 50835  
    Lid: 62321   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 47987  F
    Lid: 50033   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 52465   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 60065  
    Lid: 33777   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 59805  
    Lid: 52209   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 19778  
    Lid: 27970   StoreEc: 0x977     
    Lid: 17730  
    Lid: 25922   StoreEc: 0x977     
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hresult, SafeExInterfaceHandle iUnknown, Exception innerException)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.ExRpcConnection.Create(ConnectionCache connectionCache, ExRpcConnectionCreateFlag createFlags, ConnectFlag connectFlags, String serverDn, String userDn, String user, String domain, String password, String httpProxyServerName, Int32 ulConMod, Int32 lcidString, Int32 lcidSort, Int32 cpid, Int32 cReconnectIntervalInMins, Int32 cbRpcBufferSize, Int32 cbAuxBufferSize, Client xropClient, Byte[] clientSessionInfo, TimeSpan connectionTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiStore.OpenMapiStore(String serverDn, String userDn, String mailboxDn, Guid guidMailbox, Guid guidMdb, String userName, String domainName, String password, String httpProxyServerName, ConnectFlag connectFlags, OpenStoreFlag storeFlags, CultureInfo cultureInfo, Boolean wantRedirect, String& correctServerDN, ClientIdentityInfo clientIdentity, String applicationId, Client xropClient, Boolean wantWebServices, Byte[] clientSessionInfo, TimeSpan connectionTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiStore.OpenMailbox(String serverDn, String userDn, String mailboxDn, String userName, String domainName, String password, ConnectFlag connectFlags, OpenStoreFlag storeFlags, CultureInfo cultureInfo, WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity, String applicationId)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.ForceOpen(MapiStore linkedStore)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.ForceOpen(MapiStore linkedStore)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.Initialize(MapiStore linkedStore, LogonType logonType, ExchangePrincipal owner, DelegateLogonUser delegateUser, Object identity, OpenMailboxSessionFlags flags, GenericIdentity auxiliaryIdentity)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.<>c__DisplayClass12.<CreateMailboxSession>b__10(MailboxSession mailboxSession)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.InternalCreateMailboxSession(LogonType logonType, ExchangePrincipal owner, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String clientInfoString, IAccountingObject budget, Action`1 initializeMailboxSession, InitializeMailboxSessionFailure initializeMailboxSessionFailure)
```

any suggestions much appreciated

thanks

Rehan Miah